# Why does this File write fail after a SharePoint 2010 migration?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I migrated my MOSS 2007 application (with custom approval workflow) to Sharepoint 2010. I had this generic piece of code to log data

```
private void WriteToLog(String logInfo)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        File.AppendAllText(LOG_FILE_PATH + string.Format("{0:" + LOG_FILE_FORMAT + "}", DateTime.Now) + ".log", logInfo);
    });
}
```

I have done a database detach upgrade, there are running workflows (In progress state) from the previous environment which should continue in sharepoint 2010. But unfortunately that does not happen , my replicator activity threw an error. I found this in the sharepoint log

> System.IO.IOException: The device is not ready.
>     at System.IO._*Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullP  ath)
>
>     at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String p  ath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY*  atTRIBUTES sec  attrs, String msgP  ath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String p  ath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgP  ath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String p  ath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
>     at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String p  ath, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
>     at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String p  ath, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)
>     at System.IO.File.AppendAllText(String p  ath, String contents, Encoding encoding)
>     at xyz.Utils.MailNotific  ations.DisplayClass1._0()
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.DisplayClass4._2()
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElev  ated secureCode)
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElev  atedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElev  atedPrivileges(CodeToRunElev  ated secureCode)
>     at xyz.Utils.MailNotific  ations.WriteToLog(String logInfo)
>     at xyz.Utils.MailNotific  ations.SPNotific  ation(SPWeb applic  ation, String subject, String approver, String htmlBody)
>     at xyz.WF.Approval.ApprovalWorkFlow.logError_ExecuteCode(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Activity.RaiseEvent(DependencyProperty dependencyEvent, Object sender, EventArgs e)
>     at System.Workflow.Activities.CodeActivity.Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
>     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor`1.Execute(T activity, ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
>
>     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor`1.Execute(Activity activity, ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
>     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorOper  ation.Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime)
>     at System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()

In brief this seems to be an IO exception. I have shared the log folder location, file access permission is ruled out, the application works just fine when a new workflow is started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are LOG_FILE_PATH and LOG_FILE_FORMAT?

The IO exception could be caused if either are empty or invalid in some other way.

Comment: I have these in my web.config file as <add key="LogFileFormat" value="MMyyyyHH" /><add key="LogFilePath" value="D:\Projects\xyz\Log\" />

Comment: And when a new workflow is started, i get the log data properly.The problem is only when moving a running workflow that was initiated in MOSS 2007

Comment: I had different log file paths set in my MOSS 2007 and SharePoint 2010 application. I replicated the folder structure from my MOSS 2007 machine in the new environment and i retained the log file path location in the configuration file. It worked! Thanks for your lead!

Answer (score 2):

It can even occur if you are trying to refer to a removable medium too frequently. In my case, I was trying to display the remaining space in the disk by getting the information from the `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` method.

The code was called as soon as a few bytes were copied to the device. So, it's better to check if it's not the case. Do the exception handling and let it get the details when it is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is related but I had a console app scheduled as a task and the task kept failing with "The device is not ready" when I went to manually run the console app from the command line I was shown an error that

"to run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET framework blah blah".

[image]